# Mastering Chemistry and Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, java

For my General and Analytical Chemistry course at college there is a site called Mastering Chemistry, made by Pearson, that features different questions types. When I went to solve some problems, I was told that I needed to download and install Java. I already have Java, and all of the other questions have worked. I am running XFCE on Ubuntu 14.04.

[image]

Comment: Is there a specific version that you need? I see you have the Icedtea plugin, so you should be good to go on that front. Could it be another plugin that's causing a problem or security settings? Try running the browser in safe mode. Have you asked support at Pearson?

Comment: @Doorknob the Icedtead plugin is installed...

Comment: @ErbBetapatched Chrome doesn't support Java applets since it discontinued NPAPI. Try Firefox instead.

Answer (score 1):

Open **Firefox** and click on "addons" and select "plugins". Scroll to the java plugin and make sure it is set to either "ask to activate" or "always" (note: it should not be set to activate when not in use for security reasons).

---

If the opensource java plugin is not compatable, you can install the non-free proprietary java and plugins using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

### Again, you *must* use Firefox as these plugins are not compatable with chrome or chromium.

source: [install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html)

Comment: Could you please emphasize the use of Firefox? It it important that java applets won't work with Chrome any more.

Comment: According to [Java](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser_ubuntu.xml), you would simply have to create a symlink in /opt/google/chrome/plugins (after making that directory) that links to /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/lbnpjp2.so (or whatever path `update-alternatives --display mozilla-javaplugin` points to) in order to get it to work with Chrome as well. While the WebUpd8 PPA doesn't provide it for Chrome automatically, it should be able to be added manually.

Comment: I retract my previous comment. Did some playing around with this "fix" in Chromium and it, in fact, doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Githlar that's because recently, google chrome and chromium stopped supporting those types of plugins (NPAPI). That would have worked a few months ago but not anymore. The only alternative is to use firefox instead. If you need to use an updated version of flash you can use the pepperflash plugin with firefox by typing the following commands: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8` then `sudo apt-get update` and finally `sudo apt-get install freshplayerplugin`